# Tilemill export

Tags: shapefile, mapbox, tilemill

I have a 30 Mo shapefile (http://osm13.openstreetmap.fr/~cquest/openfla/export/departements-20140306-50m-shp.zip) that I want to use with Tilestream and Mbtiles.

Is it normal that the Tilemill export gives me a "100 GB+ reducing zoom level recommended"?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are limiting both the bounding box and the zoom range of what you are exporting, as opposed to the whole world at every level of detail.

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/exporting/

TileMill does not use the bounding box that is defined in the shape file. It defaults as the entire world.

Comment: Thanks! So maybe it's normal because shapefile and mbtiles files don't share the same usage? I can't sent 11Mo to a navigator (http://osm13.openstreetmap.fr/~cquest/openfla/export/communes-20140306-100m-shp.zip)? But I can't store 11 Mo in a mbtiles file to send some tiles to the same navigator (http://minus.com/i/bhJIqnKqPupUV and http://minus.com/i/rAKQCCMMWa6N).